# How can I quickly change the audio stream to a different device in KDE Plasma?

Tags: sound, kubuntu, kde

In Unity, if I click sound settings in the system tray, the window that comes up will allow me to change the default audio device live in one click. In KDE plasma, if I right-click on the speaker icon -> Audio Volume Settings then I come to the window below, where it appears to be impossible to change the default audio device:

[image]

I want to be able to switch the sound back and forth between my main speakers and my HDMI TV.

Answer (score 0):

To change your audio devices in KDE/Plasma, I used the "Phonon Audio and Video" application to change the device priorities. I setup the priorities in Audio Playback, then "Apply(ed) Device List to .." everything else.